# How to Reload external javascript file on asynchronous postback which document.writes() html block inside a div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to load a `.js` file into a `div` which `document.writes()` some `HTML` elements into the `div`

**Example :**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://xyz/abc.js"></script>
</div>
```

Now this `.js` file on `AJAX` asynchronous postback does not executes.

How can I re-register the file into the div? Or how can I run this `.js` file on asynchronous postBack

*Thank You.*

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the src attribute of that script element?

Comment: @Teddyberg:Can you specify? Changing src attribute to what?

Comment: are you using update panel for asynchronous postBack ?

Comment: See this post [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828764/reload-external-javascript-after-asynchronous-postback-via-updatepanel)

Comment: @Priscy Posted answer with an example.

Comment: @ArumoyRoy : Yes i am using update panel for asynchronous postBack

Comment: Why don't you keep the script part outside the update panel. You can reregister any js function inside update panel. If you give some more details about your question that would be more helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a prefixed id (just to avoid name clash) to the div and refer that id in the js file the you want to load. And add async attribute to the script tag.

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden" id="prefix-targetdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xyz/abc.js" async></script>
```

Comment: could you share me a link to the page or a Jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the **src** attribute to reload the external script. One example could be to use a made-up query string appended to the actual JavaScript URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xyz/abc.js?some-random-string-to-reload-the-external-script"></script>
```

Related question: [Refresh external loaded javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355862/refresh-external-loaded-javascript-files)